# How to remove single line from a array in the session

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, session

Hi I am trying to delete a single line from my array.

For example:

```
array:1 [▼
    5 => "2"
    4 => "1"
]
```

The key is the id and the value is the amount

How do I delete just 1 single row in my view without deleting the whole array?

I hope someone can help me out!

This is my cart controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Validator;

use App\Category;
use App\Product;

class ShopController extends Controller
{

    public function addToShoppingCart(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $this->validate($request, [
            'id' => 'required|integer|min:1|max:2147483647',
            'amount' => 'required|integer|min:1|max:100',
        ]);

        $currentCart = $request->session()->get('cart');

        if (!is_array($currentCart)) {
            $currentCart = [];
        }

        if (array_key_exists($data['id'], $currentCart)){
            $currentCart[$data['id']]+= $data['amount'];
        }else{
            $currentCart[$data['id']] = $data['amount'];
        }

        $request->session()->put('cart', $currentCart);
        return Redirect()->action('ShopController@cart');
    }

    public function cart(Request $request)
    {
        $cart = $request->session()->get('cart');
        return view('shop/cart', [
            'cart' => (is_array($cart) ? $cart:[]),
        ]);
    }

    public function delete()
    {
        unset($_SESSION['cart']['id']);
        return Redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

This is my cart view:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    @forelse ($cart as $id => $amount)
        <div class="container">
            <li>Product: {{$id}}, Hoeveelheid: {{$amount}}</li>
            <a class="btn btn-danger" href="{{ action('ShopController@delete') }}">
                Product verwijderen
            </a>
            <a href="{{ action('ShopController@clear') }}">Winkelwagen legen</a>
        </div>

        {{ dd($cart) }}
        @empty

        <div class="container">
            Er is nog niks in uw winkelwagen!
        </div>
    @endforelse
@endsection
```

I hope someone can get me out of trouble

Comment: [unset](http://php.net/unset).

Comment: ^^ That would be the one.

Comment: which value you want to delete

Comment: I want to delete the product. The product is stored in the array cart and there is a id = key and value = amount.

I have a function to delete the whole session
But I also want to delete just 1 product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jon Stirling indicated, you should use [unset](http://php.net/unset) like so:

```
unset($array[1]); // unsets element of $array with key of 1
```

Example:

```
$array = array(
    5 => "2",
    4 => "1"
);

unset($array[5]);

/**
Will output:
    Array
    (
        [4] => 1
    )
*/
print_r($array);

unset($array);

print_r($array); // Produces PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: array in test.php on line 13
```